# Fabric/Crashlytics crashing APK game. Cannot integrate in Unity 2018

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric.io

I have a Unity (2018.2.6f1) game project which has a few plugins like Admob, Facebook Audience Network, Applovin, Flurry Analytics, and AppsFlyer analytics. I am building for Android.

Everything worked and ran correctly until I recently integrated Fabric (And Crashlytics), and now my game won't run on a test device.

Now, when I compile the APK and run the game on a test device, the game freezes and then crashes. Looking at the log I see the errors are happening in Crashlytics. I cannot seem to get Fabric to work. What is going on?

I've attached the log below:

```
10-11 09:58:15.612: E/zygote(22688): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale Local 0x9  (index 0 in a table of size 0)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x9
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504] "Thread-36" prio=5 tid=44 Runnable
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13800000 self=0xb5e96200
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=22738 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xc187f970
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 40138855 21304771 188 ) utm=0 stm=4 core=5 HZ=100
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0xc1781000-0xc1783000 stackSize=1022KB
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 002c5dcf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+130)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 00358023  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+202)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00354507  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+34)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 002308ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+736)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 00230d17  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+66)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 0035bf2d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+292)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 000d1d05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+64)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 000d1315  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+220)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 000d24d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck12CheckVarArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEPKNS_7VarArgsE+184)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #09 pc 000d0b69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+600)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #10 pc 000d511b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI13CheckCallArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessERNS_11ScopedCheckEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_10InvokeTypeEPKNS_7VarArgsE+90)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #11 pc 000d5a9f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodAEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDP6jvalueNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+538)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #12 pc 000c727b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI23CallStaticObjectMethodAEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+34)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #13 pc 001d079c  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN25AndroidJNIBindingsHelpers22CallStaticObjectMethodEPvS0_RK13dynamic_arrayI6jvalueLj0EE+160)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #14 pc 001d6a84  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libunity.so (_Z40AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethodPvS_P9MonoArray+100)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #15 pc 000071a4   (???)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504]   (no managed stack frames)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): java_vm_ext.cc:504] 
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:508] Runtime aborting...
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:508] 
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x9
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516] "Thread-36" prio=5 tid=44 Runnable
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13800000 self=0xb5e96200
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   | sysTid=22738 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xc187f970
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   | state=R schedstat=( 40138855 21304771 188 ) utm=0 stm=4 core=5 HZ=100
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   | stack=0xc1781000-0xc1783000 stackSize=1022KB
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #00 pc 002c5dcf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+130)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #01 pc 00358023  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+202)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #02 pc 00354507  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+34)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #03 pc 002308ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+736)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #04 pc 00230d17  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+66)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #05 pc 0035bf2d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+292)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #06 pc 000d1d05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+64)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #07 pc 000d1315  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+220)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #08 pc 000d24d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck12CheckVarArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEPKNS_7VarArgsE+184)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #09 pc 000d0b69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+600)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #10 pc 000d511b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI13CheckCallArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessERNS_11ScopedCheckEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_10InvokeTypeEPKNS_7VarArgsE+90)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #11 pc 000d5a9f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodAEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDP6jvalueNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+538)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #12 pc 000c727b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI23CallStaticObjectMethodAEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+34)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #13 pc 001d079c  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN25AndroidJNIBindingsHelpers22CallStaticObjectMethodEPvS0_RK13dynamic_arrayI6jvalueLj0EE+160)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #14 pc 001d6a84  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libunity.so (_Z40AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethodPvS_P9MonoArray+100)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   native: #15 pc 000071a4   (???)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516]   (no managed stack frames)
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516] 
10-11 09:58:15.649: A/zygote(22688): runtime.cc:516] 
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/heroltexx/herolte:8.0.0/R16NW/G930FXXU2ERG2:user/release-keys'
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688): Revision: '8'
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688): pid: 22688, tid: 22738, name: Thread-36  >>> com.candywriter.apollo14 <<<
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688):     r0 00000000  r1 000058d2  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688):     r4 000058a0  r5 000058d2  r6 c187ed28  r7 0000010c
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688):     r8 00000002  r9 c187ed89  sl 0000000a  fp c187ed88
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688):     ip 00000000  sp c187ed18  lr e849e4c7  pc e84cf748  cpsr c187e9a8
10-11 09:58:15.650: E/CRASH(22688): backtrace:
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #00  pc 0004b748  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #01  pc 0001a4c3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #02  pc 0032e063  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+370)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #03  pc 0032e65b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Aborter(char const*)+10)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #04  pc 003e6231  /system/lib/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+456)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #05  pc 00224abb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1262)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #06  pc 00224d17  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+66)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #07  pc 0034ff2d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const+292)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #08  pc 000c5d05  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallFloatMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+88)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #09  pc 000c5315  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::IsInstanceOf(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*)+1360)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #10  pc 000c64d1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallNonvirtualShortMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+60)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #11  pc 000c4b69  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetObjectClass(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+824)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #12  pc 000c911b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+538)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #13  pc 000c9a9f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::ReleaseStringUTFChars(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*, char const*)+54)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #14  pc 000bb27b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassHierarchyAnalysis::CheckInterfaceMethodSingleImplementationInfo(art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__1::unordered_set<art::ArtMethod*, std::__1::hash<art::ArtMethod*>, std::__1::equal_to<art::ArtMethod*>, std::__1::allocator<art::ArtMethod*> >&, art::PointerSize)+726)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #15  pc 001d079c  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libunity.so (AndroidJNIBindingsHelpers::CallStaticObjectMethod(void*, void*, dynamic_array<jvalue, 0u> const&)+160)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #16  pc 001d6a84  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libunity.so (AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_CallStaticObjectMethod(void*, void*, MonoArray*)+100)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #17  pc 000071a4   ( (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.AndroidJNI:CallStaticObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,UnityEngine.jvalue[]) + 0x4c (0xb9f0b158 0xb9f0b1e8) [0xe7786ee0 - Unity Root Domain]+29092)
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #18  il ........  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.AndroidJNI.CallStaticObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,UnityEngine.jvalue[]) <IL 0x00023, 0xffffffff>
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #19  il 0000002c  at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,UnityEngine.jvalue[]) [0x00005] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJNISafe.cs:208
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #20  il 00000117  at UnityEngine.AndroidReflection.GetMethodMember (intptr,string,string,bool) [0x00057] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:681
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #21  il 0000005b  at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID (intptr,string,string,bool) [0x0000c] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:1139
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #22  il 00000033  at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID (intptr,string,string,bool) [0x00005] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJNI.bindings.cs:65
10-11 09:58:15.950: E/CRASH(22688):     #23  il 0000004b  at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID<object> (intptr,string,object[],bool) [0x0000a] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:1105
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #24  il 00000043  at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID<object> (intptr,string,object[],bool) [0x00005] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJNI.bindings.cs:159
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #25  il 0000007b  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic<object> (string,object[]) [0x0001d] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:423
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #26  il 0000003b  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic<object> (string,object[]) [0x00004] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJava.bindings.cs:91
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #27  il 00000077  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (string) [0x0001e] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:586
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #28  il 00000043  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass._AndroidJavaClass (string) [0x00013] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:606
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #29  il 0000002b  at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass..ctor (string) [0x00009] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJava.bindings.cs:101
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #30  il 00000033  at Fabric.Internal.Runtime.Utils.Log (string,string) [0x00006] in C:\Users\omnic\Documents\Unity\Projects\Relax with Words\Assets\Fabric\Runtime\FabricUtils.cs:11
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #31  il 00000047  at Fabric.Internal.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsInit.HandleLog (string,string,UnityEngine.LogType) [0x00019] in C:\Users\omnic\Documents\Unity\Projects\Relax with Words\Assets\Fabric\Kits\Crashlytics\Runtime\CrashlyticsInit.cs:89
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #32  il 0000009f  at Fabric.Internal.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsInit.HandleException (object,System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) [0x00024] in C:\Users\omnic\Documents\Unity\Projects\Relax with Words\Assets\Fabric\Kits\Crashlytics\Runtime\CrashlyticsInit.cs:83
10-11 09:58:15.951: E/CRASH(22688):     #33  il 0000007b  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this___object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00022, 0x0007b>
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #00  pc 000225d3  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #01  pc 001f7bb8  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so (mono_runtime_invoke+136)
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #02  pc 001f8f24  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so (mono_runtime_delegate_invoke+128)
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #03  pc 001f97fc  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #04  pc 001f9a88  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so (mono_unhandled_exception+404)
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #05  pc 0017618c  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #06  pc 002b5f5c  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #07  pc 0013e910  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so (mono_gc_invoke_finalizers+24)
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #08  pc 00178678  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #09  pc 0023b14c  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #10  pc 0028b6c8  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #11  pc 002c2c74  /data/app/com.candywriter.apollo14-Gyp5ZHtuEHRBnnHMgBCw0w==/lib/arm/libmono.so
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #12  pc 00048a5f  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688):     #13  pc 0001b333  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
10-11 09:58:15.954: E/CRASH(22688): memory near r1:
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Please contact us at support(at)fabric(dot)io so we can dig into this more.

Comment: was there an end result to this? I believe I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: @JasonHorsburgh I eventually resolved the issue by manually initializing Fabric, and putting the initialization code for Fabric in a coroutine that had a 2 second delay before starting.

I don't know why this solved the issue, but it works for now. I emailed the Fabric team and they are currently looking into this issue.

Comment: yuck! thanks Kevin, I'll give that a go

Comment: @KevinGonzalez Just to follow up: I triggered Fabric.Initialize() on the Start() call for my main bootstrap scene behaviour and it didn't trigger a crash. Initialising in Awake()/OnEnable() still caused the crash. Not ideal, but it will do as a workaround.